# Django tag filtering issue

Tags: python, django, tags, django-filter, django-taggit

I have a problem with my code, I want to filter the tags, to show only my articles who has the a certain tag.

here is my code:
**views.py**

```
from article.models import Article

def innertag(request, id):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)
    return render_to_response('innerajouter.html', context, Context({"articles" : Article.objects.filter(tags__name=Article.tags), "tag" : get_object_or_404(Article.tags, id=id)}))
```

---

```
"articles" : Article.objects.filter(tags__name=Article.tags)
```

This part of my code is the problem

it gives me this error message: **StopIteration at /article/tags/2 No exception message supplied**

---

**innerajouter.html**

```
<h3>For the tag: {{ tag.name }}</h3>

{% for article in articles %}
    <h1>{{ article.titre }}</h1>
    <h5>{{ article.auteur }}</h5>
    <p>{{ article.contenu }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Article(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    auteur = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    contenu = models.TextField(null=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre
```

How Can I resolve that ?

---

Solution tried :

```
"articles" : Article.objects.filter(tags=Article.tags)
```

**TypeError at /article/tags/2
int() argument must be a string or a number, not '_TaggableManager'**

Comment: I use the django-taggit package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the concrete tag and then filter articles by it:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from taggit.models import Tag

def innertag(request, id)
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, id=id)
    articles = Article.objects.filter(tags=tag)
    context = {'tag': tag, 'articles': articles}
    populateContext(request, context)
    return render(request, 'innerajouter.html', context)
```