# How to fetch related items when using taggit in django?

Tags: django, django-taggit

Using [django-taggit](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html), I'd like to fetch related posts which have the same tag(s) as the current post. Here is the views:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager, TaggedItem
from taggit.models import Tag

def post(request, post_slug):

    post = Article.objects.get(slug = post_slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    #tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, id= post.id)
    #related = Article.objects.filter(tags= post.tags.similar_objects()) 

    print "RELATED \n"   
    #print related

    d = dict(post=post, comments=comments, form=CommentForm(), 
             user=request.user)
    d.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("article/post.html", d)
```

I looked at the docs and different answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926077/4151875)) but none worked for me. So appreciate your help.

Comment: Doesn't `post.tags.similar_objects()` in and of itself provide a list with the results you desire? (see [documentation here](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.similar_objects))

Comment: @LaundroMat Yes, it does! Please answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post.tags.similar_objects()` in and of itself will provide you with a list of the results you want (documentation [here](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.similar_objects)).