# How to grab related post/item using django-taggit?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I'm new in django/python, so please bear with me.

I want to create some sort of "Related Post" in django. How I can do that? I'm following this : [How to fetch related items when using taggit in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144220/how-to-fetch-related-items-when-using-taggit-in-django)

but dont know how to use/implement it and how to render it in template. This is my view :

```
def trip_list(request):
    trip_list = Trip.objects.filter(misc_published=True).order_by('-misc_published')[:12]
    related = Trip.objects.filter(tags=trip_list.tags.similar_objects())[:3]
    return render(request, 'app_trip/trip_list.html', {'trip_list': trip_list})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

**----------- UPDATE -----------**

Okay, after babling with the code, it seems it's almost success, but it's error :

> ValueError at /trip/tour-island/
>
> Cannot query "bali island Tour": Must be "Tag" instance.

Here is my updated code :

```
def trip_single(request, slug):
    trip = get_object_or_404(Trip, slug=slug)
    trip_related = Trip.objects.filter(misc_published=True, tags=trip.tags.similar_objects())[:3]
    return render(request, 'app_trip/trip_single.html', {'trip': trip}, {'trip_related': trip_related})
```

In the template

```
{% for trip in trip_related %}
   <h1>{{ trip.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you

**----------- UPDATE [SOLVED!] -----------**

Using `model_name.tags.similar_objects()`

**In views.py** :

```
def trip_single(request, slug):
    trip = get_object_or_404(Trip, slug=slug)
    trip_related = trip.tags.similar_objects() # Where the magic happen
    return render(request, 'app_trip/trip_single.html', {'trip': trip, 'trip_related': trip_related})
```

**In template** :

```
{% for trip in trip_related %}
    <h1>{{ trip.trip_judul }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`similar_objects` is returning a `trip` list, you can write this sentence:

```
trip_related = [a_trip 
                for a_trip in trip.tags.similar_objects() 
                if a_trip.misc_published
               ][:3]
```

Comment: Hi, 

thanks for the reply. The error is gone, but still it shows nothing. I expect something like loop, but it's related post/item.

Here is my code : https://pastebin.com/WG2ExtPH (I cannot format my code here).

Thank you!